# Operations of the elements of arrays in a function' c++

Tags: c++

Can I operate the elements of an array in a function(in the parameter)?

```
float f(i, u, v)
{
    if (i == 1) {
        return (u - v); //example of the returned value
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        return (u + v);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    float x[3],y1,y2,h;
    x[1]=1;//value of the first element of x[m]
    x[2]=1;
    h=0.01;
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        y1=h * f(i, x[1], x[2]);
        y2=h * f(i, x[1] + y1/2, x[2]+y1/2);
        y3=h* f(i,x[1] + y2/2, x[2]+y2/2);
        y4=h * f(i,x[1] + y3, x[2]+y3);
        x[1]=x[1] + (y1+ 2 * y2 + 2 * y3+2 * y4)/ 6;
        x[2]=x[2] + (y1+ 2 * y2 + 2 * y3+2 * y4)/ 6;
        cout<<x[1]<<endl;
        
    }
}
```

with:
`x[1]` and `x[2]`  are the elements of the array `x[m]`
How can I operate elements of different arrays in parameter?

Comment: Please provide [mcve], it's hard to imagine the code that you didn't show to us.

Comment: Your code means: calculate the value of `x[1] + x[2] * 2`, and pass the value as the argument of the function `f`.

Comment: you asked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185114/array-elements-in-a-function-argument-in-c) before. Its still not clear why you think this isnt possible. Do you have some code that does not compile? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818:I had but I think the values calculated were not right.

Comment: what values? If you have some code that compiles but yields wrong results please show it to us

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818:I have edited the code,I think the values of the results are a way too big

Comment: whats wrong with the code? It does not print anything, so what does it do that it shouldn't or vice versa?

Comment: well the code you posted does not compile, its not possible to get wrong results with that code. Please read about [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to try to compile your code, the compiler will give you some important hints as of what is wrong. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/eWa77zoe3) is the code compiled online.

To make it compile i changed it to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nxKdhxKTb):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float f(int i, float u, float v) {
    if (i == 1) {
        return (u - v); // example of the returned value
    }
    // if (i == 2) { // This if-statement is not needed
        return (u + v);
    // }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    float x[3] = {0, 1, 1}; // x[0] is unused...?
    float y1 = 0;
    float y2 = 0;
    float y3 = 0;
    float y4 = 0;
    const float h = 0.01;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        y1 = h * f(i, x[1], x[2]);
        y2 = h * f(i, x[1] + y1 / 2, x[2] + y1 / 2);
        y3 = h * f(i, x[1] + y2 / 2, x[2] + y2 / 2);
        y4 = h * f(i, x[1] + y3, x[2] + y3);
        x[1] = x[1] + (y1 + 2 * y2 + 2 * y3 + 2 * y4) / 6;
        x[2] = x[2] + (y1 + 2 * y2 + 2 * y3 + 2 * y4) / 6;
        cout << x[1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Note the changes

- You need to specify the types for the variables in the function `f(...)`
- You need to define all variables before using them (a good rule is to specify everything right before you use it, and add const if not changed.
- Remember to zero initialize variables that you are going to add to (y1, y2... etc)

Also I would recommend you to use x1 instead of x[1](https://godbolt.org/z/eWa77zoe3), since you are mixing styles between x and y, and you are not using the zeroeth element. [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/nWafh4b4K)

```cpp
int main() {
    int i;
    float x1 = 1;
    float x2 = 2;
    float y1 = 0;
    float y2 = 0;
    float y3 = 0;
    float y4 = 0;
    const float h = 0.01;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        y1 = h * f(i, x1, x2);
        y2 = h * f(i, x1 + y1 / 2, x2 + y1 / 2);
        y3 = h * f(i, x1 + y2 / 2, x2 + y2 / 2);
        y4 = h * f(i, x1 + y3, x2 + y3);
        x1 = x1 + (y1 + 2 * y2 + 2 * y3 + 2 * y4) / 6;
        x2 = x2 + (y1 + 2 * y2 + 2 * y3 + 2 * y4) / 6;
        cout << x1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Is the code still right if I change y into an array too?

Comment: Yes probably. But then, remember that you probably want to call your y1 y[0], y2[1] etc because c++ starts arrays with index 0. I would also recommending looking at std::array in cppreference.org. (And please mark the answer as an answer to your question if you are happy with it ;) )